# Calculating time deltas between rows in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to compute the difference in timestamps and make a delta time column in a Pandas dataframe. This is the code I am currently using:

```
# Make x sequential in time
x.sort_values('timeseries',ascending=False)
x.reset_index(drop=True)

# Initialize a list to store the delta values
time_delta = [pd._libs.tslib.Timedelta('NaT')]

# Loop though the table and compute deltas
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    time_delta.append(x.loc[i,'timestamp'] - x.loc[i-1,'timestamp'])

# Compute a Pandas Series from the list 
time_delta = pd.Series(time_delta)

# Attach the Series back to the original df
x['time_delta'] = time_delta
```

It seems like there should be a more efficient / vectorized way of doing this simple operation, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Suggestions on improving this code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you miss:

- [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) possibility. With it you don't need loop by hand
- `inplace` variable in methods, e.g. [`x.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Example code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Prepare table x with unsorted timestamp column
    date_today = datetime.now()
    timestamps = [date_today + timedelta(seconds=randint(1, 1000)) for _ in range(5)]
    x = pd.DataFrame(data={'timestamp': timestamps})

    # Make x sequential in time
    x.sort_values('timestamp', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    # Compute time_detla
    x['time_delta'] = x['timestamp'] - x['timestamp'].shift()

    print(x)
```

Comment: Using [`x.time_delta.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) (possibly with `-1` as argument) might be even simpler.

Comment: Yes, `x['time_delta'] = x.timestamp.diff()` is simpler.

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer if you want.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

```
    x['time_delta'] = x.timestamp.diff().fillna(x['time_delta'])
```

This works as below, in a simpler example.

You could use the `diff()` Series method (with `fillna` to replace the first value in the series):

```
s = pd.Series([11, 13, 56, 60, 65])
s.diff().fillna(s)
0    11
1     2
2    43
3     4
4     5
dtype: float64
```

This was compiled from the comments below the current best answer (which I failed to see and kept searching), and the [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870116/get-original-values-from-cumulative-sum) that explained it with `fillna` so I am hoping this can be lifted up to the top for future seekers. Happy data processing!

Comment: An alternative to fillna(), is to drop the first element altogether. s = pd.Series([11, 13, 56, 60, 65]) s.diff()[1:] 1 2.0 2 43.0 3 4.0 4 5.0 dtype: float64